# unconsistency record data on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I'm Newbie on postgresql.
I am trying to learn how to insert sum into another table using trigger and on postgresql.

I want to insert data current_balance from table invoice_items in to table tbl_cb

this my function script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rec_cb_insert() 
RETURNS trigger AS $build_cb_insert$ 
begin
    if new.type = 'CBA_ADJ' then
    INSERT INTO tbl_cb(current_balance)
        select SUM(amount)FROM invoice_items
        WHERE account_id='6015ec0f-4d30-4802-bbcc-ea35c12f93a2' 
        and type='CBA_ADJ';
       end if;
    RETURN new;
END;
$build_cb_insert$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

this my trigger

```
create trigger insert_cb_insert
  after insert
  on invoice_items
  for each row
  execute procedure rec_cb_insert()
;
```

when I insert data without thread data coloumn curent_balance  consistency,

Without thread:

[image]

but when I use thread data coloumn curent_balance not consistency.

With thread:

[image]

[consistence_current_balance_table_tbl_cb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uWGt.png)

[unconsistence_current_balance_table_tbl_cb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP4bH.png)

how to solve it?

Update 20 sep 2019,

This new my Function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_currentbalance_3()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
 DECLARE
    current_balance numeric;
    BEGIN
        -- Check that empname and salary are given
        IF new.type IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'type cannot be null';
        END IF;

         IF  new.account_id IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'account_id cannot be null';
        END IF;

        IF new.type = 'CBA_ADJ' then
       EXECUTE'SELECT SUM(amount) FROM invoice_items WHERE 
               account_id= new.account_id and type=new.type new.invoice_id'
              into current_balance;
        insert into balance (invoice_id, balance, invoice_items_id)
        values (new.invoice_id,current_balance,new.invoice_id);
        END IF;
        -- Remember who changed the payroll when
        -- NEW.last_date := current_timestamp;
        --  NEW.last_user := current_user;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$function$
;
```

ANd this my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_current_balance AFTER
INSERT 
ON
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_insert_currentbalance3();
```

and now I get error
**Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions.**

how to solve it? :(

Comment: Can you describe what you think is inconsistent and show the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement?

Comment: coloumn current_balance, when I insert not using thread the record consistent.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uWGt.png, But when I insert using thread the record inconsistent https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP4bH.png.